# System program problem detected/ sorry ubuntu 20.04 experienced an internal error

Tags: 20.04

The "Report a problem..." window says the following:

[image: "Report a problem..."]

How can i fix this? It's getting in my nerves

Comment: Just send the report and keep installing updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Only if you're just bothered about the crash reports and not going to file a bug:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/apport &` -- to open the Apport settings
2. Change the `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` -- to disable problem reporting
3. `ctrl+x` & `ctrl+y` -- to save and close the file

Hope this helps.